# Wrong attachment when sending emails using python

Tags: python, email

I am using a python script for sending mass emails to our clients, but from the start there is a small issue. Some of them said that their files (attachments) are weird files with no extension. I checked and they sure are. To ensure myslef I added to my script addidtionally to send email to me aswell but I recive a normal looking file. The script is using files that are named in this way: "e-mail" -> " " -> "-" -> " " -> "FS" -> " " -> nr of doc with date -> ".pdf". And the weird looking ones are named just the first part of an mail, so when mail is "test@gmail.com" the file is called "test" with no extension.

```
import email, smtplib, ssl
import os
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


def send_mail(): 

    subject = "YesNet Faktura"
    body = "Dzień dobry,\n\nprzesyłamy e-fakturę, którą znajdą Państwo w załączniku.\nDziękujemy za terminowe dokonanie płatności.\n\nPozdrawiamy,\nyesNET.pl\n\nTa wiadomość została wygenerowana automatycznie. Prosimy na nią nie odpowiadać. Zapytania można kierować na: EMAIL"
    sender_email = "EMAIL"
    receiver_email = ""
    password = "PASSWORD"
    # assign directory
    a = "uploads\ "
    a = a.strip()
    directory = 'uploads'
    # iterate over files in
    # that directory
    emailsLog = []

    if len(os.listdir(directory)) > 0:
        for filename in os.listdir(directory):
            f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            # checking if it is a file
            print(f)
            print(filename)
            if os.path.isfile(f):
                filename = ""
                receiver_email = ""
                text = ""
                context = ""
                part = ""
                message = 0
                recievers = ""

                filename = f

                receiver_email = f.replace(a, "")
                recievers = receiver_email.split()
                # Create a multipart message and set headers

                # recipients = [receiver_email, "EMAIL"]

                recipients = ["EMAIL"]

                while recievers[1] != "FS":
                    recipients.append(recievers[0])
                    recievers.pop(0)


                message = MIMEMultipart()
                message["From"] = sender_email
                message["Subject"] = subject
                message["To"] = ", ".join(recipients)
                message["Bcc"] = ", ".join(recipients)  # Recommended for mass emails
                # Add body to email
                message.attach(MIMEText(body, "plain"))

                # Open PDF file in binary mode
                with open(filename, "rb") as attachment:
                    # Add file as application/octet-stream
                    # Email client can usually download this automatically as attachment
                    part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
                    part.set_payload(attachment.read())

                # Encode file in ASCII characters to send by email    
                encoders.encode_base64(part)

                # Add header as key/value pair to attachment part
                filename = filename.replace(a, "")
                part.add_header(
                    "Content-Disposition",
                    f"attachment; filename= {filename}",
                )

                message.attach(part)
                text = message.as_string()

                # Log in to server using secure context and send email
                context = ssl.create_default_context()
                with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("SMTP", 465, context=context) as server:
                    server.login(sender_email, password)
                    server.sendmail(sender_email, recipients, text)
                    print(receiver_email)
                    emailsLog.append(receiver_email)
        return emailsLog
    else:
        return False
```

I am using it as a function for my flask app. To be honest I suspect that this line might have been a problem but I dont know:

```
with open(filename, "rb") as attachment:
                    # Add file as application/octet-stream
                    # Email client can usually download this automatically as attachment
                    part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
                    part.set_payload(attachment.read())
```

I changed some of the lines to not leak any information so dont be scared of an EMAIL or PASSWORD sentences or SMTP, becouse they are information that I dont want to leak :)
much appriciation for any help! :)

Comment: Are there spaces in the file names?  It's possible some servers or agents might not handle these correctly.

Comment: Are the files clients get the same file you are attaching but with changed name? Do they open after changing the name? Is there any common mailing service affected clients use?

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes there are spaces in filename i will change it and check if it works but I dont know about thatas a problem couse the file name is still just the first part of an email address so it dousent make sense

Comment: @matszwecja No the files all have different email and nr of doc, and of course the content inside. these client all have different custom mailing services.

Comment: What I'm asking is if it is the file you wanted but with incorrect name, or is the file completely different?

Comment: @matszwecja its completely different